# I'm following a YouTube video

Tags: support, triage

Stack Overflow has a policy of requiring code as text and formatted as such. Which excludes pictures, or link to code.

I too often see the case

> I'm following a YouTube video, and at minute x I don't understand y

Should this type of question follow the same policy, should it be flagged, or what is exactly the policy on those?

I would guess it does not follow the minimal example policy, so it should be updated. But I see little consensus between the various reviews.

The last I've seen: *[need help identifying/writing code for image recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354586/need-help-identifying-writing-code-for-image-recognition)*

Comment: Guess that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: Besides that: ... I can't imagine such a question is going to be really a valuable contribution to the Stack Overflow repository. If you're following videos and don't cross-reference with better sources of information to fill gaps in your knowledge, you have more than one problem that Stack Overflow cannot help you with.

Comment: I agree, my question was more on what exactly should we do in triage. I mostly help newbies in here. Apparently this was my first question..